# Display views result from a certain entry on

Tags: views

I have a ranking list on my Drupal site (Database output sorted by points, and I assign a rank via the field "Global: View result counter"). Now, displaying the entire ranking list is no problem. But I would also like to add a view where a user can find himself in this ranking list and see the list from his position on (i.e. himself and then all users with lower points). Any idea how I could do this? Filters are not suitable, as they retrieve only a selection of the original ranking list from the database, hence the rank does not match anymore...

Thanks for your help!

Tobias

Comment: Is it a paged view? If not, is there a limit on the number of items returned?

Comment: No, it's not paged, and no, it's not limited number of items...

Comment: Then I'd personally go with an approach similar to NPC's. If you later page the list or limit the number of results, then you'd have to relook at this though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell, you have no choice right now but to write a simple custom module which would use the current user name and output themed results of a corresponding query.

Though of course it would be nice to be able to use the Views UI in this, so I understand that perhaps this is not the best solution for you.